# Method to find solution for $a^x \equiv \mod n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The congruence $5^x \equiv 1 \mod 36$ has a solution because $5$ and $36$ are relatively prime, i.e. $5$ and $2^23^2$ have no common factors.

Is there a method to find $x$?

All I can see is that $5^3 \equiv 5 \mod 6$.

Comment: What do you want to know? i.e. $a^x \equiv$ what?

Comment: @josephF Note that $5^{37} \equiv 5 \mod 36$, so your answer needs editing.

Comment: what answer are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$(6-1)^n\equiv(-1)^n+(-1)^{n-1}6n\pmod{36}$$

Check for odd$(2m+1)$ & even$(2m)$  values of $n$

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Comment: Unrelated, but does Dummit and Foote go over it in their book?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) for congruences like this.

For
$$
5^x\equiv 1 \ \bmod 36
$$

you should solve

$$
\begin{cases}
5^x\equiv 1 \ \bmod 4\\
5^x\equiv 1 \ \bmod 9
\end{cases}
$$

This way you have to deal with smaller moduli.

Comment: The same question still applies: What's the method?

Answer (score 0):

In other words you want to find the multiplicative order of $5$ mod $36$.  By Euler's theorem this divides $\varphi(36) = 12$.  Next step: try $12/2 = 6$ and $12/3 = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ a\equiv 1\pmod{np}\ \Rightarrow\, a^{\large p}\equiv 1\pmod{np^2}\ $ by $\,a^{\large p}\!-1 = (\overbrace{a-1}^{\large np\,k})(\!\overbrace{a^{p-1}+\cdots+a^2+a+1}^{\large\ \ \equiv\ 1+\cdots+1\ \equiv\ p\,\cdot 1\ \equiv\ 0\pmod{\!p}\!\!\!\!\!}\!\!)$

${\rm thus}\,\  5^{\large 2}\!\equiv 1\pmod{\!4\cdot 3}\Rightarrow 5^{\large 6}\!\equiv 1\pmod{\!4\cdot 3^2}$

**Remark** $ $ To learn more about this general idea see [LTE = Lifting The Exponent](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h401494)

Comment: But 36 is not a prime, so i'm confused. Does the rule apply to $2^2$ and $3^2$?

Comment: @Jossie We used $\,a=5^2,\  n =4,\ p = 3.\ $ Note $\,p\,$ can be any natural - see the proof.